# C#: ObservableCollection - why virtual “CollectionChanged” event?

Tags: wpf, observablecollection

Why CollectionChanged event is **virtual** in `ObservableCollection`? We have virtual `OnCollectionChanged` method, which should be enough to override event call right?

I don't see any usage of this, and also virtual events are evil. ungainly usage of virtual events can bring a lot of logical issues, but however virtual events exists even in framework.

Is this just bad design or anyone use this in real-word?

Comment: `ObservableCollection` is meant to be a base class, it would be bad design to *not* make the event `virtual`. Why do you think the opposite?

Comment: Jon, assume someone override CollectionChanged event in derived class, and leave OnCollectionChanged method the same. This make every subscribtion(even wpf engine) goes to CollectionChanged event of derived class, which breaks method OnCollectionChanged, because it fires base event, which is empty

Comment: So the author of a derived class can write bugs if they don't pay attention to what they are doing. Is that surprising? Is it the fault of the derived author or of the base author? Should `object.GetHashCode()` not be virtual because you can override it and forget to override `Equals`?

Comment: yes, but I would prefer not to use virtual events, if there is no strong reasons of this. Here I don't see any reason, because the same logic can be reached by overriding OnCollectionChanged method

Comment: Are we discussing your preferences or design decisions? If the event is not `virtual` then derived classes cannot change its underlying representation, and they cannot inspect the subscribers if they decide they want to. "I have not needed it so far" is not an argument.

Comment: Event and handler are not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can debate about base classes and design, but here's a not direct/scholastic answer, but more of an example. I personally find it great that I could extend ObservableCollection and override OnCollectionChanged. ObservableCollection is very chatty, every time you add/remove items it bombards the UI thread with property changed messages and slows it down (in the datagrid, for example, every binding in it to be updated). So, as far as I know many people  extend the ObservableCollection to suppress such notifications until they are done adding items. Just because WPF controls DataGrids/ListViews etc.. respond to CollectionChanged this works.

here's the usage, I refresh my data and instead of adding one item at a time, I populate a List then I reset the ObservableCollection with it just once which speeds up UI responsiveness enormously:

```
private void OnExecuteRefreshCompleted(IEnumerable<MyObject> result)
{
UiUtilities.OnUi(() => { _myObservableCollectionField.Reset(result, true);              
        });
```

here's my extended class:

```
public class ObservableCollectionExtended<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private bool _suppressNotification;

            //without virtual , I couldn't have done this override
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_suppressNotification)
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    public void Clear(bool suppressNotificationUntillComplete)
    {
        _suppressNotification = suppressNotificationUntillComplete;

        Clear();

        _suppressNotification = false;
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void ClearItems(bool suppressNotificationUntillComplete)
    {
        _suppressNotification = suppressNotificationUntillComplete;

        base.ClearItems();

        _suppressNotification = false;
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> list, bool suppressNotificationUntillComplete)
    {
        if (list == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("list");

        _suppressNotification = suppressNotificationUntillComplete;

        foreach (T item in list)
            Add(item);

        _suppressNotification = false;
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// clears old items, and new ones
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list"></param>
    /// <param name="suppressNotificationUntillComplete"></param>
    public void Reset(IEnumerable<T> list, bool suppressNotificationUntillComplete)
    {
        if (list == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("list");

        _suppressNotification = suppressNotificationUntillComplete;

        Clear();

        foreach (T item in list)
            Add(item);

        _suppressNotification = false;
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid denis didn't answer the quesiton "Why CollectionChanged event is virtual?" but rather the question "Why OnCollectionChanged() method is virtual?". The first question is more properly answered by Jon. You may be interested in different handling of subscribers like I did some time ago.
Let's have two different scenarios:

First scenario:
I want to raise CollectionChanged event and be sure that any delegate that is invoked within this event (list of delegates), doesn't interrupt the invoking of the following delegates in case of an exception. In other words, an event is made of a list of delegates. If I have let's say 10 subscribers (delegates) and the 3rd delegate raises an exception, I may continue invoking the rest of delegates. Standard implementation interrupts invoking.

Second scenario:
I may want to let some subscribers be prioritized (they receive the event earlier) even if they do the subscription later than others. In "add" event I can move some specific subscribers lower or higher in my custom list of delegates which is later used to raise the event..

Comment: I think in both cases it would be better to create new event, because you are adding logic which are not expected by CollectionChanged event of your class users... so gonna to confuse them..