# How to determine which collection to use in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, collections

With all the possibilities of collections to choose from when writing a WPF application, I'm unsure as to which collections to use when storing my data.  It seems like everything could work if I used `ObservableCollection`s and implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

What are some questions I should be asking myself when using collections in my View Models?  In particular, when should I use these collections? :

`ObservableCollection`

`List<ClassA>`

`IList`

`CollectionView`

`ICollectionView`

`IEnumerable`

and any others you might want to list.

and pass it an `IEnumerable`, but how do I know which is the correct collection?  Is it all based on which controls I'm using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `ObservableCollection` when you want your GUI to update when items are added or removed. An `ObservableCollection` is a list that has `ICollectionChanged` implemented automatically.

Use `List` otherwise.

Use `CollectionView` when you want to apply sorting, grouping, filtering, aka more complex operations.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the control that takes the collection as a Source to update itself when items to the collection are added/moved/removed/replaced then you must use an `ObservableCollection` and bind the control's ItemsSource (for example) to that collection.

If you were to use a `List<T>`, the bound control would not receive any notification to get updated.

This is different than updating the content of each item. No matter (I believe) which collection type you're using the content of each item would be updated only if the item object implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: it will get updated if you raise property changed on the list and the properties on the type it contains - except for on telerik:RadGridView..:) I use lists and IEnumerable all the time as lightweight + less chatter

Comment: @Denis wouldn't that force to update the entire list? I guess it's fine if you have a short list and if you don't intend to use storyboard animation for added items.

Comment: @denismorozov just so happens I'm using `telerik:RadGridView` so thanks for info.  Do you mean except as in I need to use `ObservableCollection` for RadGridView?  Keep discussing though, learning from your comments.

Comment: @NETscape, correct if you're using RadGridView, you must use an ObservableCollection<T>. I don't like it being chatty, so I extended it, check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858479/c-observablecollection-why-virtual-collectionchanged-event/16858968#16858968

Comment: @NewDev, you are correct. But it all depends on scenarios, if you add new item and save it across the wire, after which you need to get the latest items anyway - due to multi-user updates. It could be that merging incoming is less efficient, buggy vs. simply clearing the list and adding latest and raising PropChanged

Answer (score 2):

I use IEnumerable for most of my collections.

Work your way up as needed ie:

- IEnumerable: It is the lightest weight and offers the least functionality but is perfect for most situations.
- List: Includes all of the features of IEnumerable and adds features like the ability to edit the collection by adding, removing, etc.
- ObservableCollection: Includes the above and has INotifyPropertyChanged already implemented. This makes it perfect for updating a UI for a collection that has items added and removed.

Comment: So I don't need to call NotifyPropertyChanged in my ObservableCollections, right?  And IEnumerable doesn't have adding or removing?

Comment: Not exactly. INotifyPropertyChanged implemented <b>within</b> ObservableCollections i.e. in case of item being edited/removed or deleted - NotifyPropertyChanged will be called automatically. But in case you will switch ObservableCollection refference, it wont called. You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged  on that level as well.