# Busy indicator does not show until data shows

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a control in my project that provides a busy indicator (rotating circle). I'd like it to run when a user selects a file to load data into a data grid. The busy indicator does not show up until my data grid is populated though. How can I get my busy indicator to show while the data is being retrieved? I believe I'm supposed to use a thread, but am not too knowledgeable with them yet and am trying to learn. I've tried many different ways and below is my latest attempt, which I do not know if I am anywhere close.

```
public void DoWork()
{
this.StartProgressBar();

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        UIDispatcher.Current.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                if (fileCompleted != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileCompleted.SelectedFile))
                {
                    this.TestResults.Clear();

                    LoadedFileInfo info = this.Model.OpenTestCompleted(fileCompleted.SelectedFile);

                    foreach (var model in info.Sequence.Models)
                    {
                        foreach (var details in model.Tests)
                        {
                            this.TestResults.Add(new TestResultsModel(details, model.Name.Substring(0, model.Name.IndexOf('.'))));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    });
}

private void StartProgressBar()
{
    TaskScheduler scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    CancellationToken cancelationToken = new CancellationToken();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.StopProgressBar()).ContinueWith(
        m => 
        {
            this.ToggleProgressBar = true;
        },
        cancelationToken,
        TaskContinuationOptions.None, 
        scheduler);
}

private void StopProgressBar()
{
    this.ToggleProgressBar = false;
}
```

Comment: you probably want to take a look at backgroundworker: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and I looked at it, but I do not understand it enough to know if I am using the example in my situation correctly. I'm not sure how to take my code above and break it into a background task. Can you provide any help here?

Answer (score 3):

I really agree with @Ben, you should research how to use Tasks. You are creating background threads, and doing work on the UI thread in them anyway, which inevitably hold the UI thread. Try something simpler and see if it works. As far as your cancellation token goes, I don't see how and were you'd be able to reset it, as it is not a property in your class, so here's a sample without it..

How about something like this:

```
public void DoWork()
{
   //done on the UI thread
   this.ToggleProgressBar = true;

  //done on the background thread, releasing UI, hence should show the progress bar
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
      if (fileCompleted != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileCompleted.SelectedFile))
      {
          this.TestResults.Clear();
          LoadedFileInfo info = this.Model.OpenTestCompleted(fileCompleted.SelectedFile);

          foreach (var model in info.Sequence.Models)              
              foreach (var details in model.Tests)                  
                   this.TestResults.Add(new TestResultsModel(details, model.Name.Substring(0, model.Name.IndexOf('.'))));
       }
      //after all that (assumingly heavy work is done on the background thread,
      //use UI thread to notify UI
      UIDispatcher.Current.BeginInvoke(() =>
          {
             this.ToggleProgresBar = false;
          }
});
```

}

Comment: I'm guessing TestResults is an ObservableCollection (based on the tags for the question), which means it needs to be modified on the UI thread.  The OP can potentially do this using BeginInvoke for each item, but this can actually be problematic if a large number of items are involved.  The best performance for a WPF binding scenario (assuming OP doesn't want to show partial results) is to replace the entire TestResults property with a new collection, then raise an appropriate PropertyChanged notification for the TestResults property.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will look more into tasks and also try the BeginInvoke and comment back  with my results.

Comment: I would agree with @Dan Bryant. A quick test would be to change ObservableCollection to a List, still populate it in the background thread, and when done, right under the line ToggleProgressBar = false, RaisePropertyChanged("TestResults"); that should update the binding without the chatter that is created by the observable collection.

Comment: Also You can extend ObservableCollection to remove the chatter it creates when adding every item. Which will improve perfomance ten fold. Check out the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858479/c-observablecollection-why-virtual-collectionchanged-event/16858968#16858968